Как переинициализировать USB порт на RepkaPi3, RaspberryPi4?
Есть камера, подключённая через USB к одноплатнику RepkaPi3 (на RaspberryPi4 такая же проблема наблюдается), когда я отключаю полностью питание от компьютера, то после включения камера пропадает из /dev и необходимо вручную подключить заново камеру, чтобы система её увидела. Есть ли возможность перезагрузить порт USB через терминал с целью нахождения на нём устройства? Ubuntu 20.04.
Всё, что находил в интернете, было для стационарных пк.

Если усб хаб умеет управлять питанием, то для порта 4
# disable external wake-up; do this only once 
echo disabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/4-1/power/wakeup 

echo on > /sys/bus/usb/devices/4-1/power/level       # turn on
echo suspend > /sys/bus/usb/devices/4-1/power/level  # turn off

Если нет, то иногда помогает софтресет драйвера
echo "4-1" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
echo "4-1" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind


Не сработало,  к сожалению, так как отсутствует файл порта 5-1, где появляется камера при повторном подключении. Софтресет тоже

надо попробовать весь хаб передернуть. на днях попроую на оранж пи.

Итак, спустя достаточно долгое время проб, единственным работающим способом было такое решение: разрезать провод юсб, подвести плюс к камере, от камеры в канал реле, от второго канала к микрокомпьютеру. Канал открывать через GPIO. Не могу сказать, что это ответ на вопрос, ибо это не программный способ

Резать плюс не очень универсальное решение. Срабатывает не всегда хорошо. Если провод d+ притянут к vcc, то некоторые усб чипы могут запуститься и не слать ресёт при включении
